# Powershell Script: Search for BATs with specific name and run them

Tags: powershell

back with another request to try and make my life a little easier. The problem: one of the programs I use deposits BMPs (yes, bitmaps, this is an ancient app, and no, I can't configure it not to make BMPs) where I don't need them. I've got a BAT file that can sweep a folder and remove them, but what I'd really like to do is put a copy of said BAT file in each folder where it leaves them, and then every time I run a backup cycle, have it search for those BAT files, and wherever it finds one, run it. (I'd also need to know how to tell it "look in the same folder you're in"--I think I can do that by something like $searchfolder = "." but please correct me if I'm wrong)

I'm guessing this is a Get-Childitem and ForEach, but I've taken a few stabs at it and it won't work. Does anyone have an idea how to go about it?

This is what I've got so far for the parent script to find all instances of "Clear_BMPs.bat":

```
Get-ChildItem $sourceDir -Include Clear_BMPs.bat -Recurse | ForEach-Object { call "Clear_BMPs.bat" }
```

And this is what I've got in the child script, to get rid of the BMPs themselves (the filename for it is "Clear_BMPs.bat":

```
$searchfile = "*.bmp"
$targetdir = ".\"
Get-ChildItem $targetdir -Include $searchfile | foreach{ "Removing file $($_.FullName)"; Remove-Item -force $_}
```

I'm still trying to get the Clear_BMPs.bat files to work properly but in my vision it will only search the root of the folder it's in, and not recurse through subdirectories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're calling *from PowerShell*, there's no reason to involve *batch files*, given that the code is under your control.

Indeed, what you show as the content of a `Clear_BMPs.bat` batch file is *PowerShell code*, which means you need to store it in a `.ps1` file, not a `.bat` file.

Therefore, your recursive invocation that executes all `.ps1` files should look like this:

```bash
# Find all 'Clear_BMPs.ps1' scripts in the subdir. tree of $sourceDir
# and invoke them.
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -LiteralPath $sourceDir -Filter Clear_BMPs.ps1 |
  ForEach-Object { & $_.FullName }
```

And the `Clear_BMPs.ps1` files in the various directories should contain:

```bash
# Remove all *.bmp files from the same dir. in which this .ps1 script is located.
Remove-Item -Path "$PSScriptRoot/*.bmp"
```

Note the use of the [automatic `$PSScriptRoot` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psscriptroot), which refers to the directory in which the enclosing `.ps1` file is located.

Comment: Works like a dream! Now I have one other question: this is something I could probably use in more than one environment. I'd still really like to be able to get the parent BAT file to pull its enclosing directory (basically "okay, I'm in a root folder; let me search this root and all subfolders to find this PS1 to run"). I have a couple of versions made up with directories hardcoded but I'd love to have a tad more flexibility if possible.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @tnpir4002. As for your follow-up question: Instead of `$sourceDir`, use `$PSScriptRoot` in the parent `.ps1` file too, just like in the `Clear_BMPs.ps1` files.

Comment: In fairness, the parent file is a BAT instead of a PS1 (what can I say, I was raised on BATs). If there's no easy way to get a BAT to pull its enclosing directory I guess I can use a PS1 for this. Many thanks for the help!

Comment: @tnpir4002, in a batch file, use `%~dp0` (includes the trailing ``\``).

Comment: I tried this (in the parent BAT file) but it doesn't appear to work; the BAT file does run, but it doesn't trigger any of the PS1s: Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path %~dp0 -Filter Clear_BMPs.ps1 | {other arguments}

Comment: @tnpir4002, you're using _PowerShell_ syntax, which cannot be used directly in a batch file. You'll have to call PowerShell's [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe): ``powershell.exe -noprofile -c "Get-ChildItem \"%~dp0\" ..."``

Comment: I've tried incorporating that verbiage a bunch of different ways and I can't get it to work; I'll stick with running it as a PS1. Thanks though!

Comment: Done! New question asked.

Comment: @tnpir4002: ; for any future readers that may be interested: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75140247/45375