# Batch File: Identify Enclosing Directory and Assign to Variable

Tags: powershell

So I've been trying to figure out how to get a BAT file to identify the directory it's in and assign that to a variable. I've been able to get it to work as a PS1, but a PS1 requires an extra click (right-click -> "Run in Powershell"), where a BAT you can just double-click on and have it run.

This is what my BAT file looks like now (yes, I know this looks like PowerShell commands but it's contained within a BAT file):

```
@PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command "Invoke-Expression -Command ((Get-Content -Path '%~f0' | Select-Object -Skip 2) -join [environment]::NewLine)"
@exit /b %Errorlevel%

Write-Host "OPERATION: Purge BMPs from Specified Folders";
  
$sourceDir = "U:\SOMEFOLDER\"

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -LiteralPath $sourceDir -Filter Clear_BMPs.ps1 |
  ForEach-Object { & $_.FullName }
```

What this does is it looks through the folder that's hardcoded as $sourceDir and executes the PS1 scripts wherever it finds them. Since the dataset that this BAT file is part of travels between computers, I'd like to be able to run this without the need to hard-code the file path (in other words, instead of telling it "look in this folder," I want it to say "here's the folder where I'm sitting, I need to search through every subfolder").

Thanks to assistance from others smarter than I am, I've been able to make this work as a PS1 by putting "$PSScriptRoot" where you see "$sourceDir" now after the LiteralPath flag. I also know that %~dp0 plays a role in the solution, but I've tried it a couple of different ways and I can't make it work so I need some help.

Thanks!

Comment: The reason double-click does not work in PS is that it is a risk boundary to prevent users from running arbitrary, potentially malicious scripts. PS is by default associated with Notepad for that reason. For double-click, you can change that to PS directly in Windows Explorer or default apps settings, but it is not recommended as per the above. Sure, you can take the /bat/cmd approach, but, if I can do this in WE, then why bat it? Lastly, bat has no idea what PS variable names are. Hence the ```%~dp0``` thing. You can get the working dir in bat, by doing this: ```echo %cd%```.

Comment: Why over complicate this? Why not just create this as a .ps1 and simply call that .ps1 from a .bat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use `setlocal` and `pushd "%~dp0"` to first change to the batch file's own directory, so that the PowerShell code can then simply act on the *current* directory:

```
@echo off & setlocal & pushd "%~dp0" & powerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command "Invoke-Expression ((Get-Content -LiteralPath \"%~f0\" | Select-Object -Skip 2) -join \"`n\")"
exit /b %errorlevel%

Write-Host "OPERATION: Purge BMPs from Specified Folders";
  
# Act on the current dir.
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -LiteralPath . -Filter Clear_BMPs.ps1 |
  ForEach-Object { & $_.FullName }
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting the current working directory in PS Scripts.

```
'Hello world'
'Get current working directory'
$PSScriptRoot # # is the same as this %~dp0, and only works in a script run
($sourceDir = Get-Location).Path
($sourceDir = $PWD).Path
($sourceDir = (cmd /c echo %cd%))
$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path # only works in a script run
# Results
<#
Hello world
Get the current working directory
C:\Scripts
C:\Scripts
C:\Scripts
C:\Scripts
C:\Scripts\HelloWorld.ps1
#>
```

Your bat/cmd file is doing this. Calling `powershell.exe`, executing a command, and exiting.

```
@PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command "Invoke-Expression -Command ((Get-Content -Path '%~f0' | Select-Object -Skip 2) -join [environment]::NewLine)"
```

You are now back in `cmd.exe`, then you did this...

```
@exit /b %Errorlevel%
```

Then you are passing PowerShell code...

```
Write-Host "OPERATION: Purge BMPs from Specified Folders";
  
$sourceDir = "U:\SOMEFOLDER\"

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -LiteralPath $sourceDir -Filter Clear_BMPs.ps1 |
  ForEach-Object { & $_.FullName }
```

`cmd.exe` has no idea what this is; since this is PS code. If you want to run this then it must be in that launched PS session above or a different one.

Comment: I don't have a good answer about "Why BAT?" except to say that I do pretty much everything using BAT files and I just want to be consistent, that's all. There's also the fact that every time I try to do something with BATs or PowerShell I learn something new. Not trying to be a programmer but I like seeing what does what.

Comment: No worries. ***;-}*** --- no worries, as for this ***Not trying to be a programmer***, we all are programmers, whether we realize it or not. Programming is all about levels and asp[ects. It is called batch programming historically.  ***;-}***, so there's that. We all are looking to learn something new.  ***;-}*** Yet, when mixing languages, it's more prudent to do them one at a time, call them one from the other, then try a merge, and see what happens.

Comment: I just tried it, and it works like a dream! I used ($sourceDir = (cmd /c echo %cd%)) to define $sourceDir and it ran exactly as it's supposed to.

Comment: I wish you could see some of the other questions I've asked, I've built some pretty useful BAT files just from folks here on SO helping me. I've been able to automate a lot of tedious things that used to take forever to do by hand, and a lot of it is combining different clever things people have come up with to make different things happen.